# Cykod FlashWavRecorder PHP save - upload to server problem

Tags: php, upload, google-api, audio-recording

```
I believe I have most everything correctly configured for the recorder because I can
1 - Get the Flash permission prompt
2 - Start recording
3 - Listen to the playback
but when I go to save the file I can find it neither in the upload directory nor the temp dir.

I know php is working because I have tested a post - upload form successfully.

Here's the html and php:


    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>My Recorder</title>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/recorder.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var appWidth = 24;
  var appHeight = 24;
  var flashvars = {'event_handler': 'microphone_recorder_events', 'upload_image': 'images/upload.png'};
  var params = {};
  var attributes = {'id': "recorderApp", 'name':  "recorderApp"};
  swfobject.embedSWF("recorder.swf", "flashcontent", appWidth, appHeight, "10.1.0", "", flashvars, params, attributes);
});
</script>

<style>
#control_panel { white-space: nowrap; }
#control_panel a { outline: none; display: inline-block; width: 24px; height: 24px; }
#control_panel a img { border: 0; }
#save_button { position: absolute; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#play_button { display: inline-block; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="status">
   Recorder Status...
  </div>

  <div id="control_panel">
  <a id="record_button" onclick="Recorder.record('audio', 'audio.wav');" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Record"><img src="images/record.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Record"/></a>
  <span id="save_button">
    <span id="flashcontent">
      <p>JavaScript enabled and Adobe Flash Player installed, please</p>
    </span>
  </span>
  <a id="play_button" style="display:none;" onclick="Recorder.playBack('audio');" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Play"><img src="images/play.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Play"/></a>
  </div>

  <div id="upload_status">
  </div>

  <form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm">
    <input name="authenticity_token" value="xxxxx" type="hidden">
    <input name="upload_file[parent_id]" value="1" type="hidden">
    <input name="format" value="json" type="hidden">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
$save_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . "/audio";
if(! file_exists($save_folder)) {
  if(! mkdir($save_folder)) {
    die("failed to create save folder $save_folder");
  }
 }

function valid_wav_file($file) {
  $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
  $header = fread($handle, 4);
  list($chunk_size) = array_values(unpack('V', fread($handle, 4)));
  $format = fread($handle, 4);
  fclose($handle);
  return $header == 'RIFF' && $format == 'WAVE' && $chunk_size == (filesize($file) - 8);
}

$key = 'filename';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
$upload_name = $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"][$key];
$type = $_FILES["upload_file"]["type"][$key];
$filename = "$save_folder/$upload_name";
$saved = 0;
if($type == 'audio/x-wav' && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.wav$/', $upload_name) && valid_wav_file($tmp_name)) {
  $saved = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filename) ? 1 : 0;
 }

if($_POST['format'] == 'json') {
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  print "{\"saved\":$saved}";
 } else {
  print $saved ? "Saved" : 'Not saved';
 }

exit;
?>

btw - this came straight from the cykod site, I've done barely anything to it...
also, how do i convert to mp3 upon pressing the save button?
Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you ever got an answer to this, but check your folder permissions. After setting my "audio" folder such that everyone can read/write it worked. Of course this is not the best way to do this - you need to set your apache/php account to be writeable to the folder - but at least this should get you going.